# IIS 7: Disable authentication for certain client IPs

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, ip-address

I have a virtual directory that's protected with basic authentication. I'd like to disable authentication for certain IPs, so that all requests from e.g. 127.0.0.1 are allowed without asking for credentials. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a built-in way to make this happen. I ended up writing an IIS module using [the instructions by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net).

The module checks the client's IP address (using `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`), and if it is not on the exempt list, re-implements the standard basic authentication for Windows accounts (using the `LogonUser` API and setting `HttpContext.User` to a `WindowsPrincipal`). The authentication domain and list of exempt IP addresses are read from `web.config` (using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`).

Stumbling blocks included:

- I wanted to exempt the server itself, so I added `127.0.0.1` and the server's IP address to the exempt list, but also had to add `::1` (IPv6 localhost).
- I'm using this to protect access to hgweb, and for some reason I had to change the entries in `hgrc`'s `allow_push` line from `username` to `DOMAIN\username` after enabling the plugin.

Comment: Any chance to get the source code or compiled module for this?